# How to parse xml from local folder?

Tags: android

I have to  parse a local XML file located in my folder. In this example I get the XML from a URL, how can I get the XML?`

**AndroidXMLParsingActivity .java**

```
public class AndroidXMLParsingActivity extends ListActivity {

    // All static variables
    static final String URL = "http://api.androidhive.info/pizza/?format=xml";
    // XML node keys
    static final String KEY_ITEM = "item"; // parent node
    static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    static final String KEY_COST = "cost";
    static final String KEY_DESC = "description";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
        String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML
        Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);
        // looping through all item nodes <item>
        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
            map.put(KEY_NAME, parser.getValue(e, KEY_NAME));
            map.put(KEY_COST, "Rs." + parser.getValue(e, KEY_COST));
            map.put(KEY_DESC, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DESC));`
```

Comment: Where your file is saved, in Assets folder or in SD card, read the file from location it saved, use File to read the sd card or internal memory files, where as use AssetsManager to read the Assets files.

Comment: Oh, you want to know about the XML Parsing. Please refine your question accordingly. Use org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler and extend this to a class, now use the defined override methods to parse the XML. This is the code to use the parser `SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
  SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();

  XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();

  XMLParser dataHandler = new XMLParser();
  xr.setContentHandler(dataHandler);
  xr.parse(new InputSource(HttpNetIO.executeHttpGet(sb.toString())));`

Comment: Which parser are you using for parsing XML? @penny89